# Unable to Connect MQTT Paho client in android higher version

Tags: mqtt

I am not able to connect to Mqtt paho client in android high version. while it is working fine for API less than 22 and able to publish and subscribe.here is my code
build.gradle

```
repositories {
maven {
    url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/"
}


dependencies {
compile('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

MainviewActivity

```
    String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();
     client =
            new MqttAndroidClient(this.getApplicationContext(),  "url",
                    clientId);

    MqttConnectOptions authen = new MqttConnectOptions();
    authen.setKeepAliveInterval(200);

    try {
        if(client.isConnected()){
            Log.e(TAG, "already connected");
        }else {
            Log.e(TAG, "connecting.........");
             token = client.connect(authen);
        }
        token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                // We are connected
                Log.e(TAG, "onSuccess");
                status.setText("Connected");
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                // Something went wrong e.g. connection timeout or firewall problems
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure");
                status.setText("Not Connected");

            }
        });
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Not Connected");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService" >
    </service>
```

Comment: Any messages in the logs?

Comment: there is no error or exception